# SQL JOIN two tables with AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, join, average

I am trying to join two tables:

```
songs
id | song | artist
---|------|-------
1  | foo  | bar
2  | fuu  | bor
3  | fyy  | bir

score
id | score
---|------
1  | 2
2  | 4
3  | 8
2  | 6
3  | 2
```

using this SQL command:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, score.score FROM songs LEFT JOIN score ON score.id=songs.id ORDER BY songs.id, score DESC
```

What I get back is duplicates of the same song with multiple scores, I would like the score to be averaged.

```
result
id | song | artist | score
---|------|--------|-------
1  | foo  | bar    | 2
2  | fuu  | bor    | 4
2  | fuu  | bor    | 6
3  | fyy  | bir    | 8
3  | fyy  | bir    | 2
```

I tried that using:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, ROUND(AVG(score.score),1) AS 'score' FROM songs INNER JOIN score ON score.id=songs.id ORDER BY score DESC
```

But that averages all scores, not just the score of each individual song

```
result
id | song | artist | score
---|------|--------|-------
1  | foo  | bar    | 4.4
```

Comment: Scores has no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY all the fields you want to retain:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, 
    AVG(score.score * 1.0) AS AvgScore
FROM songs 
    LEFT JOIN score 
        ON score.id=songs.id 
GROUP BY songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist
ORDER BY songs.id, score DESC
```

Alternatively, you could just do this:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, 
    (SELECT AVG(Score) FROM score WHERE score.id = songs.id) AS AvgScore)
FROM songs
```

Comment: The alternate version works perfectly... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use "**group by**" songs.id

```
    SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, 
   ROUND(AVG(score.score),1) AS 'score' FROM songs 
    INNER JOIN score ON score.id=songs.id  
group by songs.id ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: No need to say this in every answer. OP asked question to get answers so definitely he will try. No harsh feelings ;)

Comment: @Prdp : i removed it . but in most of the cases we didn't get any reply at least it work or not :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this
Select a.id,a.song,a.artist,avg(b.score) as score from songs a inner join score b on a.id =b.id
Group by a.id,a.artist,a.song

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` and join data to left (`JOIN LEFT`)

try this:

```
SELECT
  songs.id,
  songs.song,
  songs.artist,
  ROUND(AVG(score.score), 1) AS 'score'
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN score ON score.id = songs.id
GROUP BY songs.id
ORDER BY score DESC
```