# aggregate tables with AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, subquery

I am new to SQL.

I checked "another solution[SQL JOIN two tables with AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229899/sql-join-two-tables-with-avg)" posted in StackOverflow.  And I don't get the meaning with this line in that article:`AVG(score.score * 1.0)` Besides, the alternative solution below doesn't work at all:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.song, songs.artist, 
    (SELECT AVG(Score) FROM score WHERE score.id = songs.id) AS AvgScore)
FROM songs
```

---

***Here are my tables:***

```
[employees]
Dep ID | SALARY
1      |  500
2      |  200
1      |  300
2      | 1000
2      |  400
3      |  200
3      |  300
```

```
[departments]
Dept ID Dep| Dept Name
1          | Volcano
2          | ShootingStar
3          | Tsunami
```

In the end, I want to create a list looks like:

```
Dept Name   | Average Salary
Volcano     | $$$
ShootingStar| $$
Tsunami     | $$$$
```

I tried various ways and hunting hints in stackoverflow for sub queries/inner join features but still can't get it.

Based on the solution in the previous link [SQL JOIN two tables with AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229899/sql-join-two-tables-with-avg), this code works:

```
-- mapping DEPT ID with NAME + average salary by DEPT --
select EMPLOYEES.DEP_ID, DEPARTMENTS.DEP_NAME, AVG(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) as AVG_S
from EMPLOYEES 
    LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS
    ON EMPLOYEES.DEP_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID_DEP
group by DEP_ID, DEP_NAME;
```

However, I want to understand the reason WHY my original one doesn't work?

```
select E.DEP_ID, D.DEP_NAME,  (select AVG(SALARY) from EMPLOYEES group by DEP_ID) as AVG_S
from EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D
where E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP
group by DEP_ID, DEP_NAME;
```

Please help!

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you wanted to write:

```
select 
    e.dep_id, 
    d.dep_name,  
    (select avg(salary) from employees e where e.dep_id = d.dept_id_dep) as avg_s
from departments d;
```

The logic of the query is to `select` from `departments` only, then use a correlated subquery to compute the average salaries of employees of the department. This avois aggregating in the outer query.

Your query fails in the following regards:

- table `employees` is in the `from` clause of the outer query
- the outer query does `group by`
- the subquery is not corelated on the department

Comment: Thank you very much! As I need to **group by**, I wonder how and when I could do that procedure as  `e.dep_id = d.dept_id_dep` plays an important role to consolidate 2 tables.  Even if I succeed with my code, I am still not very sure how to better use **group by**.